# get rid of accidentally installed packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, dpkg, downgrade

I seem to have accidentally added the system76 ppa for Pop!_OS to my Ubuntu 20.04 installation. (what is really strange is that I have not realized this...)

In the meanwhile, I have removed the ppa and entries in the list of repos that I could find. The system is close to back to normal. Nevertheless, I think I have some remainders left, at least that is how I interpret the following output:

```
$ apt list --installed  | grep pop[0-9]

accountsservice/now 0.6.55-0ubuntu13.2pop0~1605745773~20.04~d9482b1 amd64 [installed,local]
gnome-settings-daemon-common/now 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1596026424~20.04~8296153 all [installed,local]
gnome-terminal-data/now 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04pop0~1594780610~20.04~8048ed7 all [installed,local]
gnome-terminal/now 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04pop0~1594780610~20.04~8048ed7 amd64 [installed,local]
...
```

How do I now figure out to which repo these belong to, and how do I downgrade these packages to the version that is contained in the currently active repositories?

For example, I see:

```
$ apt policy gnome-settings-daemon-common
gnome-settings-daemon-common:
  Installed: 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1596026424~20.04~8296153
  Candidate: 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1596026424~20.04~8296153
  Version table:
 *** 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop0~1596026424~20.04~8296153 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     3.36.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

And:

```
$ apt-cache madison  gnome-settings-daemon-common
gnome-settings-daemon-common | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
gnome-settings-daemon-common | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
gnome-settings-daemon-common | 3.36.0-1ubuntu2 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
gnome-settings-daemon-common | 3.36.0-1ubuntu2 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
gnome-settings-daemon | 3.36.0-1ubuntu2 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Sources
gnome-settings-daemon | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 | http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Sources
```

I interpret this as indicating that the currently installed version is not contained in the repos.

But how do I revert the the version in the repository? Ideally, I'd like to do this for *all* packages...

**UPDATE** I have now manually replaced all packages with the ones I wanted, using `apt-get install package=version`. This was a major pain because I had to look up the version I needed with `apt policy` for each of these, and sometimes replace a whole bunch of packages at once to satisfy dependencies. Although my problem is solved, I therefore still am very interested in how such a clean-up could be done more efficiently.

Comment: While not answering - too complex as it is now - I'm giving you a suggestion to install `ppa-purge` and use it against any PPA that you no longer want and simultaneously want to undo whatever was installed/changed resulting from said PPA.

Comment: I already removed the ppa and some of the packages, so that this route does no longer work for me.

Comment: Have you tried apt dist-upgrade? Not sure if it would resolve everything in this case but according to man its purpose is solving conflicts by also deleting packages. On the other hand apt writes history in /var/log/apt and you can find all package installs there for a manual cleanup.

Comment: @user52366 Indeed, that was a suggestion for the future, implicitly.

Comment: I tried dist-upgrade in the hope that it would remove the packages no longer in to active repos, but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all that tedious manual clean-up work, in the end I also wrote a Python script that identifies all packages that either are not in the active repositories, or for which versions that are newer than the ones in the repositories are installed.

The code below is a quick fix and will not win a beauty competition, but for me it did the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Identify all packages that are not in active repositories or for
which newer versions are installed.
"""

import re
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint


def get_packages():
    vers = subprocess.run("apt-show-versions", shell=True, capture_output=True)
    vers = vers.stdout.decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    vers = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in vers) if y]
    not_in_archive = {}
    newer_than_archive = {}
    others = {}
    for pkg in vers:
        p = [x.strip() for x in pkg.split(' ', 2)]
        name = p[0]
        vers = p[1]
        status = p[2] if len(p) == 3 else ''
        if vers == 'not' and status == 'installed':
            continue
        if status == 'uptodate':
            continue

        tmp = {name: {'vers': vers}}
        if status == 'installed: No available version in archive':
            not_in_archive.update(tmp)
        elif status == 'newer than version in archive':
            newer_than_archive.update(tmp)
        else:
            others.update(tmp)
            others[name][status] = status

    return not_in_archive, newer_than_archive, others


def get_version(pkg):
    vers = subprocess.run("apt policy {}".format(pkg),
                          shell=True, capture_output=True)
    vers = vers.stdout.decode("utf-8").splitlines()

    vt = re.compile(r'^ +version table:', re.IGNORECASE)
    stars = re.compile(r'^ \*\*\* *')

    res = []

    while True:
        line = vers.pop(0)
        if vt.match(line):
            break

    for i, line in enumerate(vers):
        if line[:8].strip():
            s = line[:5]
            v = line[5:].split(' ', 1)[0]
            installed = bool(stars.match(s))
        else:
            p, a = line[8:].split(' ', 1)
            res.append({'installed': installed,
                        'version': v,
                        'prio': p,
                        'archive': a})
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':

    missing, newer, rest = get_packages()

    url = re.compile(r'^https?://', re.IGNORECASE)

    res = {}

    for p in newer:
        v = get_version(p)
        for x in v:
            if url.match(x['archive']):
                res[p] = x['version']
                break

    if missing:
        print("===== packages not in repositories =====")
        print(' '.join(p for p in missing))
        print()

    if rest:
        print("===== packages with other status =====")
        pprint(rest)
        print()

    if res:
        print("===== command to downgrade =====")
        print('sudo apt-get install {}'.format(
            ' '.join('{}={}'.format(p, v) for p, v in res.items())))
```

For example, after disabling my darktable and kicad PPAs, I get

```
===== packages not in repositories =====
darktable-dbg:amd64 libpng12-0:amd64 zoom:amd64

===== command to downgrade =====
sudo apt-get install darktable:amd64=3.0.1-0ubuntu1 kicad:amd64=5.1.5+dfsg1-2build2 kicad-demos:all=5.1.5+dfsg1-2build2 kicad-doc-en:all=5.1.5+dfsg1-2build2 kicad-footprints:all=5.1.5-1 kicad-libraries:all=5.1.5+dfsg1-2build2 kicad-packages3d:all=5.1.5-1 kicad-symbols:all=5.1.5-1 kicad-templates:all=5.1.5-1
```

The last command would downgrade the installed packages, and the ones above would have to be removed with `apt-get remove ...`.

(I understand that ppa-purge is the way to go if it is only about removing a ppa and everthing else in the system is 'clean', but that may not always be the case)